# EPPlus - Filters automatically added for empty cells in additional worksheets

Tags: c#, asp.net, epplus, epplus-4

I am using EPPlus to export dataset into Excel. There is no issues when i have 1 worksheet in a workbook. When i add additional worksheets, the worksheets empty cells added with filters automatically like below. Any solution to avoid such unwanted filters?

[image: excel automatically added filters]

```
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
{
DataTable sourceTable = dsSource.Tables[0];            
TableStyles tableStyles1 = OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Custom;
ExcelWorksheet worksheet1 = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(sheetName + 
"1");

ExcelRangeBase range1 = worksheet1.Cells[1,1, sourceTable.Rows.Count - 1, 
sourceTable.Columns.Count - 1].LoadFromDataTable(sourceTable, true, 
tableStyles1);

sourceTable = dsSource.Tables[1];
TableStyles tableStyles2 = OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Custom;
ExcelWorksheet worksheet2 = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(sheetName + 
"2");    
ExcelRangeBase range2 = worksheet2.Cells[1, 1, sourceTable.Rows.Count - 1, 
sourceTable.Columns.Count - 1].LoadFromDataTable(sourceTable, true, 
tableStyles2);    
package.Save();
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to add the worksheets? Nothing intrinsic in there that would cause the behaviour you are seeing.

Comment: @Stewart_R, I have added code. Can you check again?

Comment: I have just tested your code and I did not face your issue, I would say the issue is in your dataset

Comment: First of all Thanks @Stewart_R for your efforts. I am using LibreOffice to view the Excel file. That's having some issue. When i open the excel in Microsoft Excel there is no issues. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks @YahyaHussein The LibreOffice is the problem. Otherwise, no issue there when open with Microsoft Excel. Thanks again.